# JavaScript each in grep function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem using `grep` function. My code is

```
var zapis = jQuery.grep(ListaGrupa, function(v, k) {
  console.log($(that).attr("kursid"));
  if (v.grupa.ID == $(that).attr("kursid")) {
    idZaBrisanje = v.kategorija.Id;
    return true;
  }

  if ($.each(v.grupa.Podgrupe, function(kljuc, vrednost) {

    if (vrednost.podgrupa.ID == $(that).attr("kursid")) {

      idZaBrisanje = vrednost.podkategorija.Id;

      return true;
    }
  }))

    return false;

})[0];
```

But is seems return true is in each scope, so in wont affect on grep function, so I get empty results.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `return true` in this case will act instruct your `each` function to continue the iteration. It will not break out of your `grep` function.

Instead, you may want to set a flag, and then return `false`, so as to terminate the iteration:

```
var found = false;
$.each(function() {
   if(condition) {
      found = true;
      return false;
   }
});

if(found)
   return true;
```

Furthermore, `$.each` will always return the iterated object, which will always be truthy, so you can't use that inside a condition the way you're doing.

This is a scenario where you may reconsider whether jQuery is actually helping you. You may consider falling back to a regular for loop here, which would allow you to return out of the `grep` function immediately from within the iteration.

```
for(var i = 0; l = v.grupa.Podgrupe; i<l; i++) {
   var vrednost = v.grupa.Podgrupe[i];
   if(condition)
      return true;
}
```